# Getting Timezone with strftime

Tags: java, c++, simpledateformat, strftime

My time zone is `+0700`, I'm in Vietnam. I'm using C++'s`strftime` to get the timezone but the result is different to Java's `SimpleDateFormat`.

My C++ code :

```
tm* curr_tm;
curr_tm = localtime(&timenum);
char date_string[100];
std::string format = "'Timezone is :' %Z %z";
strftime(date_string, sizeof date_string, format.c_str(), curr_tm);
cout << date_string;//output: Timezone is : SE Asia Standard Time+0700
```

My Java Code :

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("'Timezone is :' zzzz Z");
result = formatter.format(new Date((long) timestamp));
System.out.println(result);//output: Timezone is : Indochina Time+0700
```

My expected output of C++ should be the same as Java. Is there a difference between the timezone format of these two libraries, and how can I get the same result as Java from C++.

Comment: I know it’s not what you asked about at all, but allow me to mention: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` in Java. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for the suggestion. I will use `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` next times if I need it.